# How to show keyboard without animation (Swift, iOS9)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I know there already are answers on this question but none of them actually work for me or at least I'm not experienced enough to implement them. Is there some straight way to achieve this? I'm getting keyboard height in method triggered by `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` (after `textField.becomeFirstResponder()`) so the best would be if someone give me concrete line of code. Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when showing keyboard not animated? because I'm sure there's a solution for you problem even if the keyboard is animated

Comment: I'm making simple trivia game (I'm only learning). I want to place game area between navigation bar and keyboard. To build game area I'm using stack views.

Comment: could you update me how you settle this?

Comment: @CaffeineShots ok, i posted answer. hope it helps. fell free to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some troubles I managed how to handle it.

Notification observer in the viewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Method anywhere in Vi

```
func keyboardShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info  = notification.userInfo!
    let value: AnyObject = info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!

let rawFrame = value.CGRectValue()
let keyboardFrame = view.convertRect(rawFrame, fromView: nil)

println("keyboardFrame: \(keyboardFrame)")
}
```